# different meanings of 'to infinitive'

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you please check if I understood them correctly?

> 1)The overwhelming majority of the houses on the Currituck Outer Banks
>   were constructed within the last decade, **most of them to accommodate
>   vacation rentals**. *(= and most of the houses were constructed in order to
>   accommodate vacation rentals.)*
>
> 2)Ford issued four recalls Thursday covering 1.3 million vehicles in
>   North America, **most of them to fix a power steering defect in SUVs**.
>   *(= and most of the recalls were issued in order to fix a power steering
>   defect in SUVs.)*
>
> 3)Over the next 200 years, around 600,000 more slaves were brought to
>   the American colonies, **most of them to work the tobacco and cotton
>   fields**. *(= and most of the slaves were brought to in order to work the
>   tobacco and cotton fields.)*
>
> 4)Hundreds of thousands more were expelled, **many of them to die in the
>   camps and the convoys**.*(= and many of them ended up dead in the camps and
>   the convoys.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have got them right. 'To-infinitive' is used to show purpose of an action, as is the case with the first three sentences, and to show the result of an action, as is the case with the last sentence.